Maximum Likelihood of Standard Deviation
I'm trying to get a better understanding about the distribution and uncertainty of the sample standard deviation. Since I'm not a mathematician, I try to compare the math literature with some simulated results.
I did a fairly simple simulation study, starting by first assuming X∼N(μ,σ²). I sample three times from this distribution and estimate the sample variance.
I used the estimated sample variance and simulated a chi-square distribution to get the upper and lower 95% CI of the variance. (I know, I could have done this simply by taking the quantiles of the distribution without simulating the results, but I wanted to have the distribution for comparison reasons). I took the square root of these results and compare them to the population standard deviation. By repeating this approach 2,500 times, I could show that the coverage of 95% confidence intervals of the sample standard deviation is approximately 95%. That is what I expected.
However, I also averaged the mode of each of the 2,500 chi square distributions, took the square root and compared this value with the square root of the average sample variance.
As known, the variance is an unbiased estimator of the true population variance, and I got 1 as result. However, the square root of the average modes, led to a result of approximately 0.77.
To understand this better, I plotted the chi square distribution of simulation 2500 and compared the mode from this distribution with the sample variance (red line).

A clear deviation between the mode and the estimated sample variance is visible. My next thought was, that this might have something to do with the maximum likelihood (ML) versus restricted maximum likelihood estimation (REML). So, I changed a minor thing. Instead of multiplying the sample variance with n-1, I multiplied it with n and repeated the process.
var_sim <- (n-1)*sample_var[i]/rchisq(n = n_sim, df = n-1)
versus
var_sim <- (n)*sample_var[i]/rchisq(n = n_sim, df = n-1)
The expected value from the sample variance was again 1 and the square root of the average modes is with approximately 0.95 now much closer to the expected value of 1. However, this came with the cost of a loss in the coverage (89%).

I expected that the mode/ maximum likelihood estimator of the chi square distribution should fall together with the sample variance. However, this was in both approaches not the case. I guess, I have a fundamental misunderstanding about the ML estimator and the mode of the chi square sample distribution, and I hope someone can shed some light into my problem.
Here the code to reproduce my results:
set.seed(09062024)

result_var <- NULL
sd_qt_upper <- NULL
sd_qt_lower <- NULL
sd_mean <- NULL
sd_mode <- NULL
sample_var <- NULL

n_sim <- 2500
n <- 3


for(i in 1:n_sim){
x <- rnorm(n = n, 0,1)
sample_var[i] <- var(x)

var_sim <- (n-1)*sample_var[i]/rchisq(n = n_sim, df = n-1)

sd_qt_lower[i] <- sqrt(quantile(var_sim, probs = 0.025))  
sd_qt_upper[i] <- sqrt(quantile(var_sim, probs = 0.975))
sd_mean[i] <- sqrt(mean(var_sim))
var_density_temp <- density(var_sim, n = n_sim, from = 0, to = 10 )
sd_mode[i] <- sqrt(var_density_temp[["x"]][which(var_density_temp[["y"]]==max(var_density_temp[["y"]]))])
}

coverage_sd <- sd_qt_upper>1&sd_qt_lower<1
mean(coverage_sd) #coverage
mean(sd_mean) #expected value based on the expected values of each chi square distribution and simulation round
sqrt(mean(sample_var)) #expected value based on initial var calculation
mean(sd_mode) #expected value based on the mode from the simulation

#plot
plot(var_density_temp, main = paste("chi square distribution simulation:", i, "\n Mode = ", 
                                    round(var_density_temp[["x"]][which(var_density_temp[["y"]]==max(var_density_temp[["y"]]))],2),
                                    "\n Sample Variance = ", round(sample_var[n_sim], 2)))
abline(v = sample_var[n_sim], col = "red", lwd = 2)
```


The maximum likelihood estimator of the variance of a normal distribution is $\frac{N-1}{N}\sigma^2$ which is biased. Hence why we use the Bessel correction of $n-1$ to cancel everything out to get it unbiased.
However, that still falls over if you try to square root the estimate of the variance and call it an estimate of the standard deviation. Jensen's inequality shows that square rooting (a concave function) estimators leads to overestimates. Note though that the bias is very small and we all use it anyway. Wikipedia gives more details
I got lost in the rest of the post, but I think/hope this largely addresses your initial concern. Apologies if I've missed the point.

Thanks a lot for your comment! Sorry, I didn't point this out, but it is clear to me, that the Bessel correction is applied for an unbiased estimation of the sample variance. What I don't understand is why the mode (i.e. ML estimator) of the sample variance distribution (i.e. chi-square distribution) does not fall together with the Bessel corrected variance estimation. This is the reason why I performed the simulation one time with (first plot) and one time without the Bessel correction (second plot). I expected at least in one of the two cases to get a mode equal to 1.41.

I had a big misunderstanding between MLE, mode and the expected value in a distribution. @Huy Pham: Thanks a lot, your explanation and links made this clear to me. I have a follow up question based on the new results and will post this as a new question.
